# How to create robust fibonacci algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have the following algorithm

```
int fib(int n)
{
    if (n == 1 || n == 2)
       return 1;
    var fibprev = 1;
    var fib = 1;
    for (var cur = 2 ; cur < n ; ++cur)
    {
       var temp = fib;
       fib += fibprev;
       fibprev = temp;
    }
    return fib;
}
```

I do not care much about raw speed but I do want the method to be robust in the face of bad input. My restriction is that the input must be between 1 and 46 and we must to throw an exception when our caller has a bug. And we don't care about raw speed. We want to have correct, robust and readable solution.

What can I do?

Comment: You just need to guard against `n <= 0`.  In that case you can throw an exception or if you choose return something like -1.  Currently it will just return 1 for those values.

Comment: Begin by stating (1) what is a good input, and (2) what are the consequences of bad input.

Comment: @EricLippert 1) Good input it's any positive number 2) the consequences of bad input - return -1

Comment: @ipetr: OK, is 1000000 a valid input? It is a positive number. So now your function has a bug; you give it a valid input and it does not do what it says on the tin. It does not give you the 1000000th fib number.  Care to revise your statement of what a valid input is?

Comment: Or perhaps you would care to revise your implementation so that it does what it says on the tin. The nature of *robust* software is first that it is *correct*. If it's not correct then it doesn't matter how strong it is; a strong, fast algorithm that gives you the wrong answers is not a good thing.

Comment: @EricLippert Yes, I would like to have a correct algorithm. Please, help me to implement it.

Comment: @ipetr: Well, do you understand the fundamental problem?  Fib grows extremely quickly; as one of the answers points out, fib(47) is over 2 billion and cannot be represented in an int. Can you write your method to operate on BigInteger instead of int?  BigInteger actually has the entire range of an integer, not just +/- ~2 billion of an int or the +/- 8 billion billion of a long. Then you will have an algorithm which actually computes the thing it says on the tin.  Once you have that then consider what the right behaviour is for error cases.

Comment: Yes, I understand the fundamental problem. So valid input it's any positive number n such that `fib(n) < maxint`. If `fib(n)> maxint` we return -1

Comment: OK, so let's say that your restriction is that the input must be between 1 and 46.  That's fine.  **Why is -1 the right answer for an input outside that range**?  Surely the caller *knows* that they are passing in an invalid value, so if they are, *they have a bug*.  Shouldn't you throw an exception when your caller has a bug?

Comment: Yes, I think I should

Comment: If I had this question in an interview then I would spend most of the interview discussing the requirements; why does the caller need to know fib numbers? What are they going to do with the output? What inputs are valid? How often is this method going to be called? If I want to memoize solutions, what's my space budget? What's my time budget? The code is trivial; understanding how it is going to be used is the hard part.

Comment: If the inputs are large, is it acceptable to use Binet's formula, and trade off time for accuracy? If the outputs are BigIntegers, how big do we expect the big integers to get?  Tens of bytes, hundreds of bytes, millions of bytes?  How are we going to manage that memory?

Comment: For me it's too hard to give the answer to all of your question. My restriction is that the input must be between 1 and 46 and we must to throw an exception when our caller has a bug. And we dont care about raw speed. We want to have correct, robust and readable solution.

Comment: @EricLippert Question is updated. Please give a deep answer to my question if you can. choose any aspect that you want (BigIntegers, memoization, etc)

Comment: If there are only 46 possible inputs then there are only 46 possible outputs.  Put them in an array and just index into the array.  That's the cheapest and easiest possible solution. Check the index first and throw an exception if its wrong.

Comment: Now, if you wanted it in a double, we'd need to switch over to Binet to estimate it to get potentially as much accuracy as we can store in a double. But, really when there's only 46 valid answers, a lookup table is the robust way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: Throws exception now, conforming to the updated question.

Ignoring the fact that it's constant time therefore maxing that raw speed thing you don't care about. Any value for n that is not acceptable returns -1; They max at 47 so that's commented out.

```
    int fib(int n) {
    switch (n) {
        case 0: return 0;
        case 1: return 1;
        case 2: return 1;
        case 3: return 2;
        case 4: return 3;
        case 5: return 5;
        case 6: return 8;
        case 7: return 13;
        case 8: return 21;
        case 9: return 34;
        case 10: return 55;
        case 11: return 89;
        case 12: return 144;
        case 13: return 233;
        case 14: return 377;
        case 15: return 610;
        case 16: return 987;
        case 17: return 1597;
        case 18: return 2584;
        case 19: return 4181;
        case 20: return 6765;
        case 21: return 10946;
        case 22: return 17711;
        case 23: return 28657;
        case 24: return 46368;
        case 25: return 75025;
        case 26: return 121393;
        case 27: return 196418;
        case 28: return 317811;
        case 29: return 514229;
        case 30: return 832040;
        case 31: return 1346269;
        case 32: return 2178309;
        case 33: return 3524578;
        case 34: return 5702887;
        case 35: return 9227465;
        case 36: return 14930352;
        case 37: return 24157817;
        case 38: return 39088169;
        case 39: return 63245986;
        case 40: return 102334155;
        case 41: return 165580141;
        case 42: return 267914296;
        case 43: return 433494437;
        case 44: return 701408733;
        case 45: return 1134903170;
        case 46: return 1836311903;
        //case 47: return 2971215073;
    }
    System.ArgumentException argEx = new System.ArgumentException("Index is out of range", "index", ex);
    throw argEx

}
```

No point is being fancy you can only get 46 valid numbers:

```
0:  0
1:  1
2:  1
3:  2
4:  3
5:  5
6:  8
7:  13
8:  21
9:  34
10: 55
11: 89
12: 144
13: 233
14: 377
15: 610
16: 987
17: 1597
18: 2584
19: 4181
20: 6765
21: 10946
22: 17711
23: 28657
24: 46368
25: 75025
26: 121393
27: 196418
28: 317811
29: 514229
30: 832040
31: 1346269
32: 2178309
33: 3524578
34: 5702887
35: 9227465
36: 14930352
37: 24157817
38: 39088169
39: 63245986
40: 102334155
41: 165580141
42: 267914296
43: 433494437
44: 701408733
45: 1134903170
46: 1836311903
^-- 32 bit signed int max ------------------------------
47: 2971215073
^-- 32 bit unsigned int max ------------------------------
48: 4807526976
49: 7778742049
50: 12586269025
51: 20365011074
52: 32951280099
53: 53316291173
54: 86267571272
55: 139583862445
56: 225851433717
57: 365435296162
58: 591286729879
59: 956722026041
60: 1548008755920
61: 2504730781961
62: 4052739537881
63: 6557470319842
64: 10610209857723
65: 17167680177565
66: 27777890035288
67: 44945570212853
68: 72723460248141
69: 117669030460994
70: 190392490709135
71: 308061521170129
72: 498454011879264
73: 806515533049393
74: 1304969544928657
75: 2111485077978050
76: 3416454622906707
77: 5527939700884757
78: 8944394323791464
^-- JavaScript Number (53 bit signed int) max ------------------------------
79: 14472334024676221
80: 23416728348467685
81: 37889062373143906
82: 61305790721611591
83: 99194853094755497
84: 160500643816367088
85: 259695496911122585
86: 420196140727489673
87: 679891637638612258
88: 1100087778366101931
89: 1779979416004714189
90: 2880067194370816120
91: 4660046610375530309
92: 7540113804746346429
^-- 64 bit signed int max ------------------------------
93: 12200160415121876738
^-- 64 bit unsigned int max ------------------------------
```

Fib is often done to show recursion. And in a pinch you just rewrite it:

```
int fib (int n) {
    if ((n > 46) || (n < 0)) throw new System.ArgumentException("FAIL!", "index", ex);
    return (n < 2)?1:fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); 
}
```

Comment: fib (int n) { 
if ((n > 46) || (n < 0)) throw new System.ArgumentException("FAIL!", "index", ex);
if (n == 0) return 1;
return n * fib(n-1);
}

Comment: Your recursive example is incorrect (it's the factorial function, not fibonacci).